# What does "the pitch is woven into" mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation

This is an article from [thebalancesmb.com](https://www.thebalancesmb.com/ways-to-get-blogging-for-money-2948406) on how to make money by blogging:

> **6. Create a blog to advertise a specific product/service.**
> *Blogs are fast becoming the trendy alternative to the classic salesletter site. In this case,
> the format is the only real change; the message is the same. Typically, **the pitch is woven
> into** as many blog entries as possible.*

Can anyone please help me understand the meaning of the phrase **"the pitch is woven into"**?

Comment: Have you check meanings for "woven" and particularly "pitch" in a dictionary..  Pitch is probably the tricky word, It is sense 4 of the second homonym on wiktionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitch#Noun_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pitch, or 'sales pitch', in the context of marketing (e.g. sales letters), is a message or act aimed at persuading readers or hearers to buy something. If it is 'woven' into blogs, it is incorporated into them, along with other matters, in a way which is compared to the way that one thread might be incorporated with others in a piece of woven cloth.

[Pitch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pitch)

[Weave](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weave)